# How to force R to auto-update column classes/types?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm reading a data file into an `R` `data.frame` where it's pretty much guaranteed that R will get the wrong class/data type because of a specific (annoying) row that's included in the file. Ironically, the line is actually declaring the data type for each column. There are 38-40 columns in these files (varies), so I'd rather not pre-define types.

Is there a way to force `R` to update the column class/data type for all columns *after* removing said line? I tried creating a new `data.frame` after removing the offending line, but that apparently doesn't force R update data types.

I've spent more time writing up this question than it would have taken to create a workaround, but I'm really curious. There must be a simple way to force R to update the data types.

Really appreciate it.

**Minimal example**

**file_1.txt**

```
  Confidence      Type   Value
       float    string     int
        1.00  deletion     110
        1.00  deletion     110
        1.00  deletion     112
        1.00  deletion     119
```

**Read data and check data types**

Here, I would obviously prefer the column data types to be `float`, `string`, and `int`, respectively, but the first row forces everything to be a factor.

```
> s <- read.table("file_1.txt", header = TRUE)
> str(s)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Confidence: Factor w/ 2 levels "1.00","float": 2 1 1 1 1
 $ Type      : Factor w/ 2 levels "deletion","string": 2 1 1 1 1
 $ Value     : Factor w/ 4 levels "110","112","119",..: 4 1 1 2 3
```

**Remove offending row and create new data frame**

```
> s <- data.frame(s[-1,])
> s
  Confidence     Type Value
2       1.00 deletion   110
3       1.00 deletion   110
4       1.00 deletion   112
5       1.00 deletion   119
```

**Data types remain the same**

I hoped creating a new `data.frame` would have forced `R` to update the data types, but no dice.

```
> str(s)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Confidence: Factor w/ 2 levels "1.00","float": 1 1 1 1
 $ Type      : Factor w/ 2 levels "deletion","string": 1 1 1 1
 $ Value     : Factor w/ 4 levels "110","112","119",..: 1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `type.convert`

Input

```
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Confidence: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1
# $ Type      : Factor w/ 1 level "deletion": 1 1 1 1
# $ Value     : Factor w/ 3 levels "110","112","119": 1 1 2 3
```

Output

```
out <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)
str(out)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Confidence: int  1 1 1 1
# $ Type      : chr  "deletion" "deletion" "deletion" "deletion"
# $ Value     : int  110 110 112 119
```

From `help(type.convert)` about the argument `as.is` (default is `FALSE`):

> as.is – whether to convert factors to character vectors. The default is to convert character vectors to factors. See ‘Details’.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Confidence = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "deletion", class = "factor"), 
    Value = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("110", "112", 
    "119"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("2", "3", "4", 
"5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I also realized after the fact that it could be really annoying behavior if simply creating a new `data.frame` would update data types. Might be nice if there were an option, though.